# plugin route error with values from link

Tags: cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-3.0

In my CakePHP 3 app I use a plugin. After one of the cake core updates I get error messages when I want to access some plugin views.

url: http://localhost/~rrd/sanga/r_brute_force/Rbruteforces/

> Error: A route matching "`array ( 'prefix' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'index', 'plugin' => 'RBruteForce', '_ext' => NULL, )`" could not be found.

**Update:** In my layout file there is a link what adds admin prefix

```
print '<li>' . $this->Html->link('Users', ['prefix' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'index']) . '</li>';
```

The next links sets prefix to false. If I change prefix to false here, everything works nicely.

Any hint why this happens?

**Update 2**
Here is my /config/routes.php

```
use Cake\Core\Plugin;
use Cake\Routing\Router;

Router::defaultRouteClass('Route');

Router::extensions(['json']);

Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
});

Router::scope('/', function($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'dashboard']);
    $routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);

    $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
});

Plugin::routes();
```

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to help you without seeing your code. I'd suggest that you search your code for the term `admin` and check back with the results, I'm pretty sure that the prefix doesn't appear out of nowhere.

Comment: @ndm Thanks, it helped. See my update, as I still do not understand what is wrong.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, no matching route exists. So what exactly do you expect to happen here? Connect to a different route (outside of the plugin maybe)?

Comment: @ndm Yes connect outside of the plugin. If I change to link above and add 'plugin' => null it works. But I still do not understand why should I do this for links where I defined prefix. Other links "know" they are outside of the plugin. I guess my cake routes.php shoud be changed but I can not figure out how.

Comment: Are you sure that they "know" that, ie have you checked the generated URLs, and they are really pointing outside of the plugin?

Comment: @ndm yes they are outside of the plugin

Comment: What does such a link (URL array) and the matching route look like, and where is it placed? I didn't managed to reproduce that, ie `'plugin' => null` will always be necessary to break out.

Comment: @ndm routes.php: https://github.com/rrd108/sanga/blob/master/config/routes.php , the menu with links: https://github.com/rrd108/sanga/blob/master/src/Template/Element/menu.ctp and the plugin: https://github.com/rrd108/rBruteForce

Comment: @ndm You are right 'plugin' => null i sneeded, but without that there is no error message. I the same time admin route gives error message. Anyway I think I understood the problem.